# Not getting callback from didReceiveScriptMessage in background

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView()` playing embedded videos. After each video ends, I get a callback message from Javascript with an index number of the next video in the array that should load.

When the app is in the foreground it works great, as well as when I press the Sleep/Wake (lock) button. When I press the Home button however, the `WKWebView` stops receiving messages and never loads the next video.

Is there a reason that the web view doesn't respond when I press the home button? It worked fine with `UIWebView` in iOS8, but I had to switch to `WKWebView` because it allowed audio to be played in the background.

The code I'm using is pretty basic and is as follows:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {

        if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {

              print(message.body)
        }
}
```

In contrast, I was getting responses from `func webView(shouldStartLoadWithRequest)` with a `UIWebView`. Any reason why `WKWebView` would be different? Or is there another function I should be using than `didReceiveScriptMessage`?

Comment: are you doing anything special when coming back from background state?

Comment: When entering foreground? I'm checking for NSUserDefault value and playing the webview using 'evaluateJavascriptFromString'. But that's not relevant, because it's an issue before I enter the foreground

Comment: right, before entering the foreground I was wondering if were doing anything special like reassigning variables that may cause a new instance of WKWebView to be created or anything like that.  It seems either the delegating method is somehow being dropped, or the thread that it is called on is being paused (Possibly by a background iOS process)

Comment: It works flawlessly if I only press the sleep/wake button. The webview proceeds to load the next video in the background. Just not after pressing the home button. There are no differences in the code that depend on whether sleep/wake is pressed or home button is pressed

Comment: I thought that the lock button puts it into a suspended state, but the home button puts in into a background state for a few minutes, 10 I think, and then suspends it.  I will have to look this up

Comment: 'applicationDidEnterBackground' is called when both are pressed. And we have background privileges for playing music. And according to 'UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationState', it goes to background mode for both

Comment: yeah, I just tested this,  the lock button does not force it into a suspended state.  If your code works fine on the lock button and not the home button, then there may be something going on in the SDK that we just have no control over.  I did poll the notifications, and there are differences between the two buttons,  so, one of those notifcations may be messing with WKWebView

Comment: Notifications called by lock not by home: `NSWillBecomeMultiThreadedNotification` and `UIApplicationSuspenedEventsOnlyNotifcation`   Notifications called by home and not by lock: `UIApplicationSuspendedNotification`,`UIStatusBarStyleOverrideDidChangeNotification` x 2,`_UIApplicationDidFinishSuspensionSnapshotNotification`

Comment: I have a similar issue. Works in UIWebView, but not in WKWebView. Is there a way to ensure WKWebView remains responsive, even when backgrounded?